# Вывод копии каталога Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно вывести весь каталог (список категорий, страница категорий, карточка товара), а точнее сделать ссылку на минифицированную копию (без header, footer и т.п.). Нужен совет как поступить лучше. Есть идея написать пару файлов, которые будут подгружать данные средствами wp. Но может есть более грамотный вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте отдельный файл шаблон, скорректируйте его в соответствие с требования по header-footer, сделайте вывод копии каталога с помощью шорткодов

- [products]
- [product_category]
- [product_categories]

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9

Comment: Спасибо большое. А что сделать с ссылками? Мне к примеру нужно, чтобы перемещение по категориям/карточкам товаров было непосредственно без перехода на каталог с основным шаблоном. Через js подменять их, а позже обрабатывать на этой же странице будет хорошей идеей?

Comment: @rutruyokko можно хуками все корректировать